# auto_ptr and forward declarations

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

I know this:

```
#include <memory>
class A;
class B 
{ 
  public:
      B(A* a) : a_(a) {}
  private:
      std::auto_ptr<A> a_;
};
```

runs afoul of undefined behaviour unless you have an out of line definition of `B::~B()`;

And at one point, gcc used to say this:

> blah/auto_ptr.h: In destructor 'std::auto_ptr<_Tp>::~auto_ptr() [with _Tp = B]': test.hh:6:   instantiated from here
>
> blah/auto_ptr.h:173: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined.

and we could detect that and fix the code before anything bad happens. Sometime this stopped happening. Is there any compiler option to switch this on (-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic doesn't seem to cut it)

A note: Moving to C++11 and `unique_ptr` is not an option for various reasons, and as far as I read it, the same issue exists with unique_ptr.

Comment: The design of `std::auto_ptr` is fundamentally flawed. Even if you cannot move to C++11 or newer, you should consider ditching `auto_ptr` in favour of alternative solutions. It is so flawed, that the type will be completely removed from the standard library in C++17.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such problem with unique_ptr, because you bind deletor when you construct unique_ptr object:

```
  struct A;
  struct B {
    std::unique_ptr<A> p;
  };
  struct A {
    ~A() {
    }
  };
  {
    B b;
    b.p = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A()); // here is you bind default_deletor of already completed type
  }
```

As the result the generated destructor for the class B destroys the p member correctly.

**UPDATE:**

If you do not plan to migrate to C++11, you could you something like unique_ptr smart pointer to eliminate the problem with auto_ptr.

Comment: As stated in the question, using unique_ptr is *not* an option

Comment: @TomTanner but "and as far as I read it, the same issue exists with unique_ptr" is not true

Comment: that isn't the reason moving to C++11 is not an option

Comment: @TomTanner nobody forces you, of cause you decide yourseft what you should do

Answer (score 0):

Actually...

libstdc++ makes the instantiating of `std::unique_ptr` a compiler error:

```
#include <memory>
class A;
class B 
{ 
  public:
      B(A* a) : a_(a) {}
  private:
      std::unique_ptr<A> a_;
};
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f93cb6a913d7964)</kbd>

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/memory:81:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of 'void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = A]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:236:17:   required from 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = A; _Dp = std::default_delete<A>]'
main.cpp:6:21:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:74:22: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'A'
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
```

Although such checking doesn't seem to be required, it's trivial to implement, so the implementations of C++ standard library are expected to have such checks.

Comment: @TomTanner It's the response to the "the same issue exists with unique_ptr". If this is preventing you from migrating, then you see it's not an issue.

Comment: that's not what is preventing me from migrating. My question was in any case more about the fact auto_ptr is compiling without a warning